# React default value does not show in input field

Tags: reactjs

I am using Django with React and I am trying to update user profiles, below is what I have tried:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        username: '',
        fetched_data: {}
    }

async componentDidMount() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  config.headers["Authorization"] = `Token ${token}`;

  await axios.get(API_URL + 'users/api/user/', config)
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({fetched_data: res.data})
    })
}

onInputChange_username(event){
    this.setState({username: event.target.value});
}

<form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} >

    <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input
            placeholder="Username"
            className="form-control"
            value={this.state.username ? this.state.username : this.state.fetched_data.username}
            onChange={this.onInputChange_username}
        />
   </div>
</form>
```

I first tried to fetch the user data in componentDidMount() and I stored it in this.state.fetched_data. In the form I tried to set the value to this.state.username if it exist. If it is empty string I then set it to this.state.fetched_data.username.

The problem I am having with the above code is that when I tried to change the field in username, I was not able to erase the value in the input field completely. Each time the field is empty, it reset to the value in this.state.fetched_data.username. I also tried to use the defaultValue like this:

```
<div>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input
        placeholder="Username"
        className="form-control"
        defaultValue = {this.state.fetched_data.username}
        value={this.state.username}
        onChange={this.onInputChange_username}
    />
```

But it also does not work since it only shows the placeholder in the input filed. How do I make this work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your using both defaultValue and value, remove defaultValue and maintain  this.state.username as initial value as ' ' and in componentDidMount assign fetch data value to this.state.username again , and use this same in onChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your conditional assignment of the value of the input field in the render function. When you try to clear the value of the field it just resets to `this.state.fetched_data.username` so you can never clear it.

Set the initial state when you load the form:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        username: this.state.fetched_data.username,
    });
}
```

Then set the value of the input field in `render`:

```
<input 
    value={this.state.username}
    onChange={this.onInputChange_username}
/>
```

And your onChange handler is fine as it is:

```
onInputChange_username(event){
    this.setState({username: event.target.value});
}
```